# Java project's output does not print ä or ö correctly in Windows command prompt

Tags: java, output, command-prompt

I have a simple java code snippet that prints out text. This is what the code snippet looks like:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Pelisäännöt.");
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code from the Windows command prompt the output does not print ä's and ö's properly. This is the output.

```
Pelisõõnn÷t
```

I am using Gradle and Netbeans to manage this "project", my Java version is 1.8.0_261 and I am using Windows 10 command prompt. I have not changed any settings of the command prompt or customised it in any way.

How can I make the ä's and ö's display properly?

Comment: Can the Windows terminal normally display ä and ö? Maybe the chosen font does not support it? Do you use the same encoding in Java and in the terminal? (I'd set both to UTF-8).

Comment: What code page is you command prompt using? Run command `chcp` without arguments and it will show you.

Comment: @Robert How do I know what font I am using and how can I change it? I changed the command prompts code page to 65001, before it was different. Now the ä's and ö's don't dipslay at all. So something definitely changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make the scandinavian characters display correctly.

1. Change code page to 1252 by running command chcp 1252
2. Change the font the command prompt is using to "Lucida Console" by right clicking on the command prompts window and selecting "Properties" -> "Font" -> "Lucida Console".

Thank you for all the answers, they helped me in arriving at the conclusion!

Answer (score 0):

By default your command prompt is not set to UTF-8. You can use `chcp 65001` to change it to use UTF-8.  You also must be using a font that supports the characters.

Comment: It must be the font now I guess, since I changed the code page to 65001 and it now displays no ä's and ö's at all. How can I change the font?